# How do I upload FBA Inbound Shipment carton weight and carton dimensions information via the MWS or SP API interface?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am aware we need to send in a feed POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS (XSD is [image: enter link description here]) but this feed has no mentions of dimensions, nor weight. NonPartneredSmallParcelPackageInput only TrackingId。What can we do?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think for a non-partnered carrier you don't have to tell amazon the carton dimensions or weights. If you're using a partnered carrier, you're effectively buying the shipping from amazon. They need the weights and dimensions so they know how much to charge you. They will give you an url to download shipping labels.
But for a non-partnered carrier that doesn't apply. You're responsible for getting your own shipping labels, and amazon doesn't know or care how much it costs you to ship your stuff to the fba warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the in the `putTransPortDetails` api call use `SP` as `shipmentType`.
There is a `PackageList` in the `PartneredSmallParcelDataInput`. The `PackageList` is weights and dimensions.

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/fulfillment-inbound-api-v0-reference#partneredsmallparceldatainput

I don't know why they don't just let you give the weights and dimensions with the cartons, that would make a lot more sense, but that doesn't work.